# mingw compiler on linux, how to get millisecond resolution

Tags: c++, linux, time, mingw, wine

I have some code that I am cross compiling on Linux with MinGW/Wine (there are windows libraries that I am being forced to use). So I am compiling on Linux with g++.exe

I have a need in this code to get the current time with millisecond resolution. When compiling with standard g++, I usually use something like this:

```
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&now);
```

This gives the error:

```
error: aggregate 'time2()::timespec now' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

What is the equivalent that I can use that would work with g++.exe compiler?

EDIT, the compilation cmd is:

```
g++.exe -std=c++0x -g -Wall -O2 -o test.exe test.cpp
```

Comment: click on timespec see which header it points. <time.h>

Comment: I have both #include <time.h> and #include <ctime> and still the same error.

Comment: if you do `g++ -M myfile.cpp` you'll get a list of files that `myfile.cpp` is including. Check that all of the headers that you are including are actually the "windows version". To me, this looks very much like "mixed up headers"

Comment: If you're willing to use some Win32 calls in your code, you could switch to using the high-res performance counters, even from MinGW.  (I use them in my cross-platform Intellivison emulator to great effect.)  This article describes how to use them:  http://cplus.about.com/od/howtodothingsi2/a/timing.htm   You can see how I used them in my own code here:  http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/intv/jzintv-1.0-beta4/src/plat/plat_lib.c  (Scroll down to `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` )

Comment: @MatsPetersson, can you elaborate on what you mean? You mean I should include something like #include <windows_time.h> instead? How do I find the names of the windows versions? Passing -M option gives no output.

Comment: The compiler error means that `struct timespec now` is being interpreted as a declaration of a new type, which means the right header for `timespec` has not been included. Since you're writing C++ you can just say `timespec now` without `struct`, but that doesn't solve the problem of the Win32 `<time.h>` header not defining `timespec`.